# How can I hide Top apps from Windows 10 search?

Tags: windows-10

The Windows 10 May 2019 update added a new feature to the search menu called Top apps which lists your most used apps.

[image: Top apps]

I want to hide this list from the search menu, just like you can do from the start menu.

I tried disabling *Show most used apps in start*, which, as the name suggests, only hides this from the start menu. I also tried *disabling Store my activity history on this device* and clearing my activity history in Windows 10's privacy settings. While disabling this option hid my recently opened files from the search menu, it didn't hide Top apps.

How can I hide Top apps from the search menu?

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to this. Maybe there is a registry hack somewhere?

Comment: I couldn't find in the whole Internet! I hope you find soon and help me too.

Answer (score 1):

This fix is applied and tested under windows 10 - 1903 and 1909 (Published latest 12/11/2019).

following solution :

set setting on search windows following setting :

[image]

or with local gpo (gpedit.msc) following settings :

[image]

clean file cache on :

`C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState`

results :

[image]

before

Comment: This removed the "Top Apps" section for me, but it also seemed to have cleared the entire search index. For example, searching for "Wordpad" returned 0 results.