# Removing search bar "Suggested" apps list

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I want to remove/disable list of suggested apps on the search bar (Windows 10). All of them are irrelevant and annoying, and serve no purpose to me. There are few reddit/Microsoft supports posts about it, but all of them either have no solution or the solution is to hide search bar entirely. Additionally it'd be perfect to also remove/customize "top apps".

Edit: This question: ([How can I hide Top apps from Windows 10 search?](https://superuser.com/questions/1443843/how-can-i-hide-top-apps-from-windows-10-search)) is not helpful as removing Cortana cache doesn't (or no longer) affect "Top apps".

[Default search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACbaf.png) [Without suggested apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fU3H.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide Top apps from Windows 10 search?](https://superuser.com/questions/1443843/how-can-i-hide-top-apps-from-windows-10-search)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: The solution suggested in the duplicate post has some negative consequences - see the comment below the answer.

Comment: (1) You could try the suggestion in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-remove-change-top-apps-in-windows-11/98d6dd12-ae83-4080-8f2e-f59427ad84d7) last entry, but all hacks have their drawbacks. (2) [Power Start Menu](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/power-start-menu/9PD5H6J2MR90?hl=en-US&gl=US) may help (commercial). (3) The only sure solution is to replace the Windows Start menu with a third-party product.

Comment: [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-app-recommendation-settings-in-windows-f21b5c60-e996-4ee4-c2cf-b4a90c0bef9b#ID0EBD=Windows_10) is the proper way to disable the suggested applications